# My headphones keep pausing, turning the volume up and down and opening Siri while listening to music

Tags: iphone, itunes, audio, headphones, siri

I have had my iPhone 11 Pro for around 2 years now and this problem started last year. Every time I put in one type of headphones, doesn’t matter if it’s from Kmart of offical apple ones, it ALWAYS pauses my music, turns the volume up and down and opens siri. It’s has annoyed me for so long. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!